# How to set background image in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-container, flutter-scaffold

I have started learning flutter recently, I want to add background image and on it I want to add two flat buttons, But I am not able to do it, I have added background image in code, but it is not working I didn't understand the problem. Could anyone help me out?

```
    void main() {
      return runApp(
        MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Ani & genny',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Pacifico',
                    color: Colors.white,
                  )),
              backgroundColor: Colors.red,
            ),
            body: MyApp(),
          ),
        ),
      );
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      void navigateToPage() {
        print('Button pressed!!!!');
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Center(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage("images/Ani.png"),
                fit: BoxFit.cover

                ),
                ),

              ),
              FlatButton(
                  child: Image.asset(
                    'images/li.png',
                    height: 120,
                    width: 120,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    navigateToPage();
                  }),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Kalyani Deshmukh, upload the code of what you have done so I can render help where needed

Comment: use `Stack` widget. [Here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html) are some details.

Comment: I have uploded code above @RandomGuru

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample code which puts a button on the image. You can use Positioned widget to place wherever you need.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
           Image.network(
              'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
           ),
           FlatButton(
              child: Text("Submit"),
              onPressed: () {
                  navigateToPage();
               }),
        ],
     ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can run this code [here](https://codepen.io/mcsukhi/pen/NWGwvVz) on codepen.

Answer (score 1):

First rap your Center with a Container.

```
Container(
  decoration:BoxDecoration(
   image:DecorationImage(
     fit:BoxFit.fill
     image: AssetImage("images/Ani.png"),
 )
    )
  child:Center(
  )
)
```

BoxFit.fill will make the image cover the container fully